# Discord.js - Deleting a specific channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm actually making a discord bot with **discord.js**, and I was wondering how to do a command to delete a specific channel with a name
ex : `!delete #general`

I already tried to do the following:

```
if (command == "delete") {
  channel.delete(args.join(" "))
  }
```

but it doesn't work so I'm kinda stuck
thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the [`.delete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=delete) method to delete a guild textchannel. 
I added a new variable `fetchedChannel` which tries to fetch the channel by its name from `args`.

**Try to use the following code:**

```
const fetchedChannel = message.guild.channels.find(r => r.name === args.join(' '));

if (command === 'delete') {
    fetchedChannel.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That code now is old if you are going to up-date(with discord.js v12) it try with:

```
const fetchedChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel_id);
fetchedChannel.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to delete a specific channel with eval command then use this code**

```
t!eval 
const fetchedChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID");
fetchedChannel.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

`message.channel.delete();`

you can put it in client.on like this

`client.on("message", message => {`
`message.channel.delete()`
})